# iOS Metal: command buffer execution order

Tags: ios, metal

Suppose I commit two commands buffers modifying the same texture, generated from the same queue:

```
var a: MTLCommandBuffer
var b: MTLCommandBuffer
...
a.commit()
b.commit()
```

Then, suppose I wait for the second one to complete:

```
b.waitUntilCompleted()
```

Is it possible that `b` gets completed before `a`? According to the documentation for `commit()`,

> The command buffer is executed after any command buffers enqueued before it on the same command queue

Does this imply that `b` will finish executing after `a` finishes or that it will just begin executing after `a` begins executing?

Comment: This is not really an answer to your question, but do you have a good reason for using two command buffers? Can you not encode all the work into the same command buffer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of [`commit`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlcommandbuffer/1443003-commit), assuming here the buffers are in the same queue:

> The command buffer is executed after any command buffers enqueued before it on the same command queue.

This is logical since one `MTLCommandQueue` will only execute one buffer at a time. So `b` will start executing after `a` has executed and waiting for it means both will have finished when it has finished.

Comment: `a` starts before `b` does not guarantee that `a` must finish before `b`. So this answer is not complete.

Comment: @JimmyChen Your statement is absolutely invalid in this case, as the question refers to a specific case which is well-documented. Indeed, queues are ordered and fully thread-safe, giving you guarantee of the expected execution order. Worth reading: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/MetalProgrammingGuide/Cmd-Submiss/Cmd-Submiss.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014221-CH3-SW1.